# Issue tracker / user feedback django app

Tags: django, bug-tracking, issue-tracking

I am looking for a Django app that can be embedded into a site and collects user feedback, such as

- Bug/issue

  - the app would have to collect information like HTTP variables, etc. to help debugging this issue
  - with backend hooks so that it can be embedded into Trac or hg bugs
- User feedback
- Wishes

Binging/Googling around I didn't find any useful app.

Comment: Sounds like a good project to start! I know most project now use hosted apps like GetSatisfaction etc.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same issue and found this helpful: http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/ticketing/

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out http://code.google.com/p/django-voice/?

Comment: I think OP is looking for something like this bundled with a button which will be displayed on all the pages of the site. And if a user wants to report an error, he will click that button and a "feedback" will be created in this system attached with the metadata like the browser info, url etc. Something like this: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-debug-toolbar but modified to be more secure.